# How to install slowmoVideo on 15.04

Tags: 15.04, slowmovideo

I have tried building from source and downloading the PPA none works because it hasnt been upgraded to 15.04 yet, so is it possible to install  slowmoVideo on 15.04?

Also here is the link http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/download.php

Error from CMAKE:

```
asher@Asher-Dell-PC:~/slowmoVideo/build$ cmake -DENABLE_TESTS=FALSE ../src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using qt5
CMake Warning at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Script" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5ScriptConfig.cmake
    qt5script-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Script" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Script_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Script" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:64 (find_package)


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:64 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake

  but it set Qt5_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt5" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Failed to find Qt5 component "Script" config file at
  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Script/Qt5ScriptConfig.cmake"





Qt libraries found at : Qt5::Gui /  
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28") 
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   found libavformat, version 56.1.0
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   found libavcodec, version 56.1.0
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   found libavutil, version 54.3.0
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   found libswscale, version 3.0.0
-- checking: avformat.h
--           /usr/include/libavformat
-- checking: avcodec.h
--           /usr/include/libavcodec
-- checking: avutil.h
--           /usr/include/libavutil
-- checking: swscale.h
--           /usr/include/libswscale
-- FFMPEG libraries are at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so
CMake Warning at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake:273 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Script" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5ScriptConfig.cmake
    qt5script-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Script" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Script_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Script" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:78 (qt5_use_modules)
  slowmoVideo/project/CMakeLists.txt:56 (qt_use_modules)


CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake:275 (message):
  Can not use "Script" module which has not yet been found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:78 (qt5_use_modules)
  slowmoVideo/project/CMakeLists.txt:56 (qt_use_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/asher/slowmoVideo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation from source should work properly on Ubuntu 15.04.

1. Install build tools :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev libqt4-dev freeglut3-dev libglew1.5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libjpeg-dev libopencv-video-dev libopencv-highgui-dev libopencv-dev
   ```
2. Install the `ffmpeg` library :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
   ```
3. Compile `slowmoVideo` from source :

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/slowmoVideo/slowmoVideo.git
   cd slowmoVideo/
   mkdir build
   cd build/
   cmake -DENABLE_TESTS=FALSE ../src
   make
   ```
4. Install it using `checkinstall` :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   Why `checkinstall` ?

   > CheckInstall keeps track of all files installed by "make install" or
   >   equivalent.   It creates a .deb package and adds it to the installed
   >   packages database.   This allows easy package removal later. —  [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the PPA for ffmpeg is broken

Comment: Sorry I corrected it **;-)**

Comment: Still doesnt work this time Cmake gives me an error. I updated the question with the error message

Comment: FIXED: I needed to uninstall QT5